# jQuery UI with Google Apps script

Tags: jquery-ui, google-apps-script

Is it possible to use a jQuery UI widget with a google apps script application?
I have a textbox and I would like to use a date picker on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Apps Script has built in DateBox and DatePicker classes in the UiApp Service. They are not yet in the documentation but if you type the reference to a UI instance into the Script Editor and add the trailing period, there are create methods for both. Google says they are working on adding the documentation. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1059)

Comment: Thank you for this information! But do you know how to retrieve the date in the DatePicker?

Comment: Ignore the question I found by myself.

Answer (score 20):

Yes you can use JQueryUI with Google Apps Script. I suggest you look at example code, there's nothing special you need to do to make them work. Just make sure to develop your application using HtmlService and not UiService, you can't mix and match. Here's an example  I [lifted straight from them](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test.html');
}
```

test.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Choose date:<input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /></div>
    <script>
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to "s it possible to use a jQuery UI widget with a google apps script application?". Not what was marked as one.

Comment: this code show the picker, however doesn't select a date when clicking on the calendar -- I am using Chrome / Linux

Comment: I agree that using Html Service is much better - it lets you use whichever JS libraries you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

You must watch the new services of google apps script:

[Google I/O 2012 - Use What You Know: HTML and JavaScript in Apps Script](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcl24asytos)

Answer (score 1):

No, in Google Apps Script you're limited to use the provided APIs. Specially when talking about Ui.