# Using Html service, get date input - calendar pop up

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get a basic html page working with the google html service. As of now I have:

```
<div>
<h1>Welcome to some random page</h1>
<p>Please select a date below:</p>
<input type="date" name="classDate" onselect="google.script.run.dateSelect()">
</div>
```

In a regular html file I get to pick a date from a little calendar view, but in this google web app I can't seem to do that. I see the 'UI service' from google has a datepicker ( [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker/) ) but I dont understand how to get it into my webapp. How do I get the little calendar pop up in this google web app? - UI date picker or not.

I've added the date picker to my code.gs file but it still doesnt come up.

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function dateSelect() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("change");
  var date = app.createDatePicker().setPixelSize(150, 150).addValueChangeHandler(handler).setId("date");
  app.add(date);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: you can't mix UiApp and HTML service, try the JQuery datepicker as shown in an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336163/jquery-ui-with-google-apps-script/13977188#13977188

Comment: Thanks. With the HTML service can you send data to a spreadsheet using the spreadsheetApp service?

Comment: yes you can... it's pretty well explained in the documentation... see best practices and here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/?hl=fr-FR. see also answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't mix UiApp and HTML service, try the JQuery datepicker as shown in the example below :

read also [the doc here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html.html').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

html.html

```
<div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Choose date : <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" />
<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
</script>

</div>
```

online example : [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyTvxU8q9sw42Q3j81EZxMiOXRmxcxZjl8d2jxUP8uZb8S7HG0/exec)

And about your comment on using SpreadsheetApp, [see doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=fr-FR)

---

edit : following comments about speed, here is a version that link to the Google hosted library to be faster. Added some style too (online example updated)

```
<div class="demo" >
<style type="text/css"> .demo { margin: 30px ; color : #AAA ; font-family : arial sans-serif ;font-size : 10pt } 
                            p { color : red ; font-size : 14pt } 
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h1>Welcome to some random page</h1>

<p>Please select a date below :</p>

click here : <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" />

<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
</script>

</div>
```

You can also choose a different style...
try to replace "smoothness" with "redmond" or "south-street", doc is on the [JQuery site](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3a%22themes%22)

Comment: I noticed there is about a 3 second delay for loading the app with jquery installed. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: Also look at the best practices for HTMLservice which suggests where the script load should be placed