# How to prompt user response on a standalone Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

So in my standalone Google Script, I have to take in a user input that will ultimately allow me to get information about a user's Google Calendar.

The CalendarApp object does not have a getUI() method nor a "Tools > Script editor" menu command.

So I've been told that "The script can prompt the user for input and then call on the Calendar API to do something like add a Calendar event."

I just have no idea how to prompt the user from a standalone script without the getUI() method. Thanks!

Comment: You will have to build a webapp. Doc here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: @Sergeinsas ok makes sense, but in the link you provided, it says "f you build a user interface for a script", and I just want to know how do you even build a user interface for the script before deploying it. All I need is to just take in a string from the user and that's it

Comment: You have to build a small user interface using HTMLService, there are examples in the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/     and here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Comment: why not trying the JQUERY UI to get your date value ? see example (among [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Djquery+date) on this forum) :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489253/using-html-service-get-date-input-calendar-pop-up/21491856#21491856

Comment: @Sergeinsas does jquery differ greatly from javascript, becuase my project has to be coded in Google Scripts. I'll look into the link

Comment: JQUERY is a JavaScript library that can be used in Google Apps script, there is a demo webapp in the answer I referred to.

Comment: by the way - if you create a new apps script file in google drive and then choose "Web App", you will also get a good example of how to use jquery in a web app.

Comment: Hi there @Anthony! Follow the examples shared above to build and interface, and check out the [web apps structure guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en) and [HTML service best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices?hl=en). Feel free to drop a comment if you need further help.